# How to silently install a certificate on Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome-os

I am looking for a way to silently install a device or client certificate from an application in ChromeOS.

Is there a way to bypass the standard dialog when installing a pfx format certificate on Chrome OS?

Thanks,

Comment: If you find a way, please report it as a security issue immediately. The dialogs are there for a very good reason.

Comment: There was a problem with the method.

We would like to create a mechanism to install pkcs#12 format certificate information without providing a passphrase to the user of the device.

The purpose of this is to prevent unintentional misuse or misappropriation of pkcs#12 format certificates in environments where MDM, etc. are not available.

It will use the usual import dialog mechanism, but it would be better if the passphrase can be given by the application.